# Sliding drawer from top to bottom didn't hide the Activity below content in android

Tags: android, android-layout, slidingdrawer

I'm using this custom Sliding Drawer from top to bottom in this [link](http://blog.sephiroth.it/2011/03/29/widget-slidingdrawer-top-to-bottom/).

It works but my problem is that I want to hide the content of the Activity below it when the sliding drawer is shown .

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a background color (or image) for the content of the sliding drawer... it defaults to transparency.

To set the background color to black for the drawer (which will cover everything underneath it), add this to your xml file:

```
android:background="#000"
```

This should go in the section with the `android:id="@+id/content"`.

Comment: Hmm, it works for a standard sliding drawer, so I must assume that something must be different in the modified class. If I get a chance later I'll browse through that code and see if I can figure it out.